# Synchronized set from map or set from synchronized map?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, synchronization, set

I need a concurrent weak hash set without using Guava collections.
Which one is correct?
Any side effects?

```
private Set<Session> subscribers1 = Collections.newSetFromMap(
        Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<Session, Boolean>())
);
private Set<Session> subscribers2 = Collections.synchronizedSet(
        Collections.newSetFromMap(new WeakHashMap<Session, Boolean>())
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the implementations, it's *almost* the same.

`Collections.newSetFromMap` creates a new `SetFromMap extends AbstracSet` instance. The `SetFromMap` class is basically a wrapper around a map object. But it does inherit the `addAll` method from the `AbstracSet`. This means that in the first option:

```
private Set<Session> subscribers1 = Collections.newSetFromMap(
        Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<Session, Boolean>())
);
```

not all operations will be synchronized (namely the `addAll` method - though it uses the synchronized `add` method under the hood). Due to this fact I'd recommend choosing the second option:

```
private Set<Session> subscribers2 = Collections.synchronizedSet(
        Collections.newSetFromMap(new WeakHashMap<Session, Boolean>())
);
```

Comment: "not all operations will be synchronized (namely the `addAll` methods)" - I don't think this is right since `AbstractCollection.addAll` loops and calls `add`, which will delegate to the wrapped map's synchronized `put` method. But that still implies that synchronizing at the top-most view will be more efficient for bulk methods so your recommendation seems right at least.

Comment: You're right that it calls `add` which is synchronized. But the `addAll` as it would be in the second option. That's what I've meant (I did check the implementation of addAll). Anyway it's the only difference between the two approaches, at least I can't see any other. It is hard to think of an use case in which this difference would be a big problem, though.